# CSS prevent horizontal scrollbar from pushing down content

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, webkit, scrollbar

I styled my own horizontal scrollbar which appears when a container is hovered. My SCSS:

```
.container {
  width: 600px;
  /* the height cannot be fixed */
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  &:hover, &:focus {
    overflow-x: auto;
    /*Scroll bar nav*/
    &::-webkit-scrollbar {
      height: 10px;
    }               
    /* Track */
    &::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
      background: #fafafa;   
    }
    /* Handle */
    &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      background: #c1c1c1;;  
    }
    /* hover effect for scrollbar thumb */
    &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover   {
      background-color: #7c7b7c;
    }
  }
}

.content {
  width: 1200px;
}
```

It works fine but when the scrollbar appears, it pushes down the content below it. How can I make the scrollbar appear inside the container, without pushing content?

I tried:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar { position: absolute; }
```

or

```
::-webkit-scrollbar { position: fixed; }
```

but it does not work. I set up a codepen for a demonstration:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OemWgR

**Note:** The container cannot have a fixed height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I had to set overflow to auto and place the custom scrollbar height outside the hover selector in order to generate the space for it. I only add the scrollbar styles in the hover selector to make it visible.

```
.container {
  width: 600px;
  /* the height cannot be fixed */
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
  /*Scroll bar nav*/
  &::-webkit-scrollbar {
    height: 10px;
  } 
  &:hover, &:focus {                    
    /* Track */
    &::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
      background: #fafafa;   
    }
    /* Handle */
    &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      background: #c1c1c1;;  
    }
    /* hover effect for scrollbar thumb */
    &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover   {
      background-color: #7c7b7c;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

If we cannot set the height to a fixed value, we can also use jQuery or native JavaScript to dynamically change the height.

For example with jQuery:

```
 $(() => {
    let h = $('.container').height() + 10 // plus the height of scrollbar
    $('.container').css({'height': h+'px'})
  })
```

---

Original answer:

Give a fixed height value to the container box, for example, 100px, as follows:

```
.container {
  width: 600px;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```js
$(() => {
  let h = $('.container').height() + 10 // plus the height of scrollbar
  $('.container').css({'height': h+'px'})
})
```

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  border: 2px solid teal;
}

.container:hover,
.container:focus {
  overflow-x: auto;
  /*Scroll bar nav*/
  /* Track */
}

.container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 10px;
}

.container::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background: #fafafa;
}


/* Handle */

.container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #c1c1c1;
  ;
}


/* hover effect for scrollbar thumb */

.container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background-color: teal;
}

.content {
  width: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <p>Vestibulum fringilla sit amet augue. Cras non dolor. Aenean ut eros et nisl sagittis vestibulum. Sed mollis, eros
      et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Cras varius. Vestibulum
      fringilla sit amet augue.
      Cras non dolor. Aenean ut eros et nisl sagittis vestibulum. Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum
      aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Cras varius.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <p>This content is being pushed down by the scrollbar &#9785; &#9785; &#9785;</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the height of the container cannot be fixed. I updated my question.

Comment: I find an alternative solution. You can use jQuery or native JavaScript, get the current height of the container box, and dynamically set the height plus the height of the scrollbar.

Comment: Thanks for this answer but I found how to do it with just CSS. There is usually always a way to do it with CSS before using JS. I posted the answer.